# Java Beginner, Why does my Program keep terminating?

Tags: java

Trying To create a calculator, Done a lot of this before about 4 years ago and just getting back into java. It just keeps terminating, it doesn't print out anything, runs for approx 5 seconds then terminates. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The problem was with the main function. The problem is fixed, thank you!

Adding the OOJCalculation code for those wanting to laugh at my stupidity more

```
public class OOJCalculation {


 int Calculation (int Num1, int Num2, String Function,int Num3){

    if(Function == "+"){

        Num1 += Num2 = Num3;

        return Num3;
    }

    else if(Function == "-"){

        Num1 -= Num2 = Num3;

        return Num3;
    }
    else if(Function == "*"){

        Num1 *= Num2 = Num3;

        return Num3;
    }

    if(Function == "/"){

        Num1 /= Num2 = Num3;

        return Num3;
    }
    return Num3;

}
```

}

```
public class Main {

public static void main(){
    int State = 0;
    int Num1 = 0;
    int Num2 = 0;
    String Function = "";
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    OOJCalculation calc = new OOJCalculation();

    while(State < 5){
    if(State == 0){
        System.out.println("Enter first number.");
         Num1 = reader.nextInt();
        State++;
    }
    if(State == 1){
        System.out.println("Enter the function.");
         Function = reader.next();
        State++;
    }
    if(State == 3){

    System.out.println("Enter the second number.");
     Num2 = reader.nextInt();
    State++;
    }

    if(State == 4){
        calc.Calculation(Num1, Num2, Function);
        System.out.println(calc);
    }

}

}
```

}

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Debug it using print statements. Then come here

Comment: Can't find what could give you that, so as _assylias_  said, provide a mcve. The funny thing is that your `while` loop is no necessary

Comment: 1. Please fix your indentation. 2. Have you debugged it? What is the value of State that you give it? Are there any errors that show before it terminates?

Comment: Edit your answer and add your `OOJCalculation` class

Comment: As per your code main method doesn't contains argument -
public static void main(String [] args). add those and try it once again

Comment: Please learn and follow Java coding standards.  Your code is harder to read b/c you do not follow them.  This code is not good.

Comment: You should know that your loop and every if are not necessary. You can read normally every value on after the other (careful with the reading of Int and String. I took the liberty to clear it a bit

Answer (score 0):

As the [jls](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.1.4) state :

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

So your program is not running because it can't find the `main`.

EDIT :

Just saying about your code, the loops and conditon are not necessay.

```
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    int State = 0;
    int Num1 = 0;
    int Num2 = 0;
    String Function = "";
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter first number.");
    Num1 = reader.nextInt();
    reader.nextLine(); //Read the <enter> key

    System.out.println("Enter the function.");

    Function = reader.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter the second number.");
    Num2 = reader.nextInt();
    System.out.println(Num1 + Function + Num2);
}
```

Comment: That Returns Just "1+2" instead of 3

Comment: Of course, I didn't use your class, I let you manage that part. ;) This was only about the unecessary lines in the main

Answer (score 0):

Your main method is missing mandatory argument:

```
public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args){
    ....
   }
}
```

Secondly it will be terminating, because it will reach the end of the block, and then have no more instruction to run.

Your OOJCalculation method is invalid:

```
   int calculation(int num1, int num2, String function) {
    if ( "+".equals(function)) {
        return num1 + num2;
    } else if ( "-".equals(function)) {

        return num1 - num2;
    } else if ( "*".equals(function)) {
        return num1 * num2;
    }else if ( "/".equals(function)) {
        return num1 / num2;
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operator");
}
```

it should start with lowerCase. Use also lov\wwer case for variables. CamelCase are reserved for class names and constructors. You have also wrongly declared returned type. Above implementation is covorrected.

Comment: It is valid, it is not the standard but this is valid.

Comment: From language point of view-yes. But not from programming culture point of view.

Comment: That I agree! Not for every langage probably but we, Java devs, like CamelCase.

Comment: Note : not sure he know about exception, so the return was more about a default value, but you should correct the String comparison ;) just noticed that